# Dragging element below image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm using JQuery draggable to make a DnD application but I have this problem.
When I drag my "boxes" into the image, they go below it so you can't see them.
This is my html and css:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">

  <div>
    <div id="item1" class="item item1 ui-widget-content">
  </div>
    <div id="item2" class="item item2 ui-widget-content">
  </div>
    <div id="item3" class="item item3 ui-widget-content">
  </div>
    <div id="item4" class="item item4 ui-widget-content">
  </div>
    <div id="item5" class="item item5 ui-widget-content">
  </div>
    <div id="item6" class="item item6 ui-widget-content">
  </div>
    <div id="item7" class="item item7 ui-widget-content">
  </div>
    <div id="item8" class="item item8 ui-widget-content">
  </div>


<br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div class="dash">
    <img src="image1.png">

    <div id="slot1" class="ui-widget-header">
     <p>holder</p>
    </div>

    <div id="slot2" class="ui-widget-header">
      <p>holder</p>
    </div>

    <div id="slot3" class="ui-widget-header">
      <p>holder</p>
    </div>

    <div id="slot4" class="ui-widget-header">
      <p>holder</p>
    </div>

    <div id="slot5" class="ui-widget-header">
      <p>holder</p>
    </div>

    <div id="slot6" class="ui-widget-header">
      <p>holder</p>
    </div>

    <div id="slot7" class="ui-widget-header">
      <p>holder</p>
    </div>

    <div id="slot8" class="ui-widget-header">
      <p>holder</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

```
.content { position: relative; }

.item { 
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px; 
  padding: 5px; 
  float: left; 
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0; 
  font-size: .9em; 
  display: inline-block;
}

.item1 {background: darksalmon;}
.item2 {background: cyan;}
.item3 {background: darkgreen;}
.item4 {background: lightpink;}
.item5 {background: lightgreen;}
.item6 {background: brown;}
.item7 {background: purple;}
.item8 {background: orange;}

.dash { 
  position: relative;
}


.ui-widget-header, .ui-widget-content { margin: 0; display: inline-block; margin: 10px;}

.ui-widget-header{
  background: lightgrey;
  border: solid;
}


#slot1 { height: 75px; width: 75px; position: absolute; top: 23px; left:37px; }
#slot2 { height: 75px; width: 75px; position: absolute; top: 23px; left:129px;}
#slot3 { height: 75px; width: 75px; position: absolute; top: 55px; left:445.5px;}
#slot4 { height: 75px; width: 75px; position: absolute; top: 233px; left:571.2px;}
#slot5 { height: 75px; width: 75px; position: absolute; top: 233px; left:656px;}
#slot6 { height: 75px; width: 75px; position: absolute; top: 233px; left:742px;}
#slot7 { height: 75px; width: 75px; position: absolute; top: 233px; left:828px;}
#slot8 { height: 75px; width: 75px; position: absolute; top: 197.5px; left:9px; }
```

In this codepen you can see they go below the "holders" boxes:
https://codepen.io/gezzzz/pen/ZNapaQ

I tried in every way I could think of tweaking the CSS but I can't find out what causes this

How can I fix this?

Comment: That worked, thank you. Yes I intend to do that, I started with the CSS inside the HTML  ```<style>``` tag and just copied it out

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer for you and expanded on it slightly too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you need to set `z-index` on the `.item` elements higher than that on the `#slotN` elements. By default they are set to `1000`.

Also note that there is a lot of unecessary repetition in your JS and CSS where you're using the unique ids of the elements. Instead put common classes on them and then select by those instead. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  const correct = [{
    slot: "slot1",
    item: "item3"
  }, {
    slot: "slot2",
    item: "item5"
  }, {
    slot: "slot3",
    item: "item2"
  }, {
    slot: "slot4",
    item: "item7"
  }, {
    slot: "slot5",
    item: "item7"
  }, {
    slot: "slot6",
    item: "item4"
  }];

  var answers = [{
    slot1: ""
  }, {
    slot2: ""
  }]

  $(".item").draggable({
    cursor: "pointer"
  });

  $('.slot').droppable({
    drop: handleDropEvent
  });
});


function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
  var item = ui.draggable;
  var slot = $(this).attr('id');
  ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this),
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left top'
  });
}
```

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
}

.item, .slot {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10001;
}

.item1 { background: darksalmon; }
.item2 { background: cyan; }
.item3 { background: darkgreen; }
.item4 { background: lightpink; }
.item5 { background: lightgreen; }
.item6 { background: brown; }
.item7 { background: purple; }
.item8 { background: orange; }

.dash {
  position: relative;
}

.slot {
  background: lightgrey;
  border: solid;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  position: absolute;
}

#slot1 {
  top: 23px;
  left: 37px;
}

#slot2 {
  top: 23px;
  left: 129px;
}

#slot3 {
  top: 55px;
  left: 445.5px;
}

#slot4 {
  top: 233px;
  left: 571.2px;
}

#slot5 {
  top: 233px;
  left: 656px;
}

#slot6 {
  top: 233px;
  left: 742px;
}

#slot7 {
  top: 233px;
  left: 828px;
}

#slot8 {
  top: 197.5px;
  left: 9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <div id="item1" class="item item1 ui-widget-content"></div>
    <div id="item2" class="item item2 ui-widget-content"></div>
    <div id="item3" class="item item3 ui-widget-content"></div>
    <div id="item4" class="item item4 ui-widget-content"></div>
    <div id="item5" class="item item5 ui-widget-content"></div>
    <div id="item6" class="item item6 ui-widget-content"></div>
    <div id="item7" class="item item7 ui-widget-content"></div>
    <div id="item8" class="item item8 ui-widget-content"></div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="dash">
      <img src="image1.png">
      <div id="slot1" class="slot ui-widget-header">
        <p>holder</p>
      </div>
      <div id="slot2" class="slot ui-widget-header">
        <p>holder</p>
      </div>
      <div id="slot3" class="slot ui-widget-header">
        <p>holder</p>
      </div>
      <div id="slot4" class="slot ui-widget-header">
        <p>holder</p>
      </div>
      <div id="slot5" class="slot ui-widget-header">
        <p>holder</p>
      </div>
      <div id="slot6" class="slot ui-widget-header">
        <p>holder</p>
      </div>
      <div id="slot7" class="slot ui-widget-header">
        <p>holder</p>
      </div>
      <div id="slot8" class="slot ui-widget-header">
        <p>holder</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-widget-header {
    background: lightgrey none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium solid;
    z-index: -1;
 }
```